# Cannot connect Firebird Server

Tags: lan, firebird

i have problem with Firebird2.5-superclassic server@Lubuntu 13.10.

I can't connect to the server through local network. I can connect only from server machine.

When i want to connect using Flamerobin:

```
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Service::Connect
Message: isc_service_attach failed

SQL Message : -902
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements

Engine Code    : 335544721
Engine Message :
Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.0.200".
Failed to establish a connection.
```

I can connect to ssh or ping server machine.

> netstat -pln

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      905/fb_smp_server
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1058/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      908/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      763/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      908/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      763/cupsd       
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1058/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           954/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54863           0.0.0.0:*                           679/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 192.168.0.200:123       0.0.0.0:*                           1313/ntpd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           1313/ntpd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           1313/ntpd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           679/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55108           0.0.0.0:*                           954/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 fe80::2e0:18ff:fe7b:123 :::*                                1313/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                1313/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                1313/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 :::54938                :::*                                954/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                679/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::55751                :::*                                679/avahi-    daemon: r
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8706     603/bluetoothd      /var/run/sdp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7315     1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8781     679/avahi-daemon: r /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10012    1035/X              /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10011    1035/X              @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8572     578/dbus-daemon     /var/run    /dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10485    1249/dbus-daemon    @/tmp/dbus-bN1Q0WLptk
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     7605     258/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9661     763/cupsd           /var/run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10435    1242/dbus-daemon    @/tmp/dbus-Pv81DSxLyY
```

Any ideas?

--
Solved - change

> RemoteBindAddress = localhost

to

> RemoteBindAddress =

in firebird.conf file.